# Can I change bootstrap 3 to bootstrap 4 in my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I used bootstrap 3(bootstrap-sass gem) in my project. But I want to change it to a fourth bootstrap (gem 'bootstrap'). I change the line `gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.4.1'` to `gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.4.1'` and do `bundle install`. 
When I open the site, I get an error `We're sorry, but something went wrong.`.
Can bootstrap code 3 work correctly on bootstrap 4?

I changed all the code in the `application.html.erb` and `index.html.erb` to simple `<p>Hello</p>`
But I still get the same error.

logs:

```
Processing by PostsController#index as HTML
  Rendering posts/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  [1m[36mPost Load (0.6ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" ORDER BY created_at DESC[0m
  ↳ app/views/posts/index.html.erb:4
  [1m[36mAuthor Load (0.7ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "authors".* FROM "authors" WHERE "authors"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:7
  [1m[35m (1.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "impressions"."ip_address") FROM "impressions" WHERE "impressions"."impressionable_id" = $1 AND "impressions"."impressionable_type" = $2[0m  [["impressionable_id", 42], ["impressionable_type", "Post"]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:8
  [1m[35m (0.8ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."post_id" = $1[0m  [["post_id", 42]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:8
  [1m[36mActionText::RichText Load (0.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "action_text_rich_texts".* FROM "action_text_rich_texts" WHERE "action_text_rich_texts"."record_id" = $1 AND "action_text_rich_texts"."record_type" = $2 AND "action_text_rich_texts"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4[0m  [["record_id", 42], ["record_type", "Post"], ["name", "content"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:21
  Rendered /home/vyacheslav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actiontext-6.0.1/app/views/action_text/content/_layout.html.erb (Duration: 1.2ms | Allocations: 362)
  [1m[36mActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4[0m  [["record_id", 42], ["record_type", "Post"], ["name", "picture"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:22
  [1m[36mCACHE Author Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "authors".* FROM "authors" WHERE "authors"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:7
  [1m[35m (0.6ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "impressions"."ip_address") FROM "impressions" WHERE "impressions"."impressionable_id" = $1 AND "impressions"."impressionable_type" = $2[0m  [["impressionable_id", 41], ["impressionable_type", "Post"]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:8
  [1m[35m (0.5ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."post_id" = $1[0m  [["post_id", 41]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:8
  [1m[36mActionText::RichText Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "action_text_rich_texts".* FROM "action_text_rich_texts" WHERE "action_text_rich_texts"."record_id" = $1 AND "action_text_rich_texts"."record_type" = $2 AND "action_text_rich_texts"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4[0m  [["record_id", 41], ["record_type", "Post"], ["name", "content"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:21
  Rendered /home/vyacheslav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actiontext-6.0.1/app/views/action_text/content/_layout.html.erb (Duration: 0.6ms | Allocations: 253)
  [1m[36mActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.5ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4[0m  [["record_id", 41], ["record_type", "Post"], ["name", "picture"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:22
  [1m[36mCACHE Author Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "authors".* FROM "authors" WHERE "authors"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:7
  [1m[35m (0.6ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "impressions"."ip_address") FROM "impressions" WHERE "impressions"."impressionable_id" = $1 AND "impressions"."impressionable_type" = $2[0m  [["impressionable_id", 40], ["impressionable_type", "Post"]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:8
  [1m[35m (0.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."post_id" = $1[0m  [["post_id", 40]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:8
  [1m[36mActionText::RichText Load (0.7ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "action_text_rich_texts".* FROM "action_text_rich_texts" WHERE "action_text_rich_texts"."record_id" = $1 AND "action_text_rich_texts"."record_type" = $2 AND "action_text_rich_texts"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4[0m  [["record_id", 40], ["record_type", "Post"], ["name", "content"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:21
  Rendered /home/vyacheslav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actiontext-6.0.1/app/views/action_text/content/_layout.html.erb (Duration: 1.4ms | Allocations: 253)
  [1m[36mActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4[0m  [["record_id", 40], ["record_type", "Post"], ["name", "picture"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:22
  [1m[36mCACHE Author Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "authors".* FROM "authors" WHERE "authors"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:7
  [1m[35m (0.8ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "impressions"."ip_address") FROM "impressions" WHERE "impressions"."impressionable_id" = $1 AND "impressions"."impressionable_type" = $2[0m  [["impressionable_id", 39], ["impressionable_type", "Post"]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:8
  [1m[35m (0.5ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."post_id" = $1[0m  [["post_id", 39]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:8
  [1m[36mActionText::RichText Load (0.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "action_text_rich_texts".* FROM "action_text_rich_texts" WHERE "action_text_rich_texts"."record_id" = $1 AND "action_text_rich_texts"."record_type" = $2 AND "action_text_rich_texts"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4[0m  [["record_id", 39], ["record_type", "Post"], ["name", "content"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:21
  Rendered /home/vyacheslav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actiontext-6.0.1/app/views/action_text/content/_layout.html.erb (Duration: 0.6ms | Allocations: 253)
  [1m[36mActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.5ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4[0m  [["record_id", 39], ["record_type", "Post"], ["name", "picture"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:22
  [1m[36mCACHE Author Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "authors".* FROM "authors" WHERE "authors"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:7
  [1m[35m (0.5ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "impressions"."ip_address") FROM "impressions" WHERE "impressions"."impressionable_id" = $1 AND "impressions"."impressionable_type" = $2[0m  [["impressionable_id", 38], ["impressionable_type", "Post"]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:8
  [1m[35m (0.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."post_id" = $1[0m  [["post_id", 38]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:8
  [1m[36mActionText::RichText Load (0.5ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "action_text_rich_texts".* FROM "action_text_rich_texts" WHERE "action_text_rich_texts"."record_id" = $1 AND "action_text_rich_texts"."record_type" = $2 AND "action_text_rich_texts"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4[0m  [["record_id", 38], ["record_type", "Post"], ["name", "content"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:21
  Rendered /home/vyacheslav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actiontext-6.0.1/app/views/action_text/content/_layout.html.erb (Duration: 3.4ms | Allocations: 744)
  [1m[36mActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4[0m  [["record_id", 38], ["record_type", "Post"], ["name", "picture"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:22
  [1m[36mCACHE Author Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "authors".* FROM "authors" WHERE "authors"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:7
  [1m[35m (0.9ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "impressions"."ip_address") FROM "impressions" WHERE "impressions"."impressionable_id" = $1 AND "impressions"."impressionable_type" = $2[0m  [["impressionable_id", 37], ["impressionable_type", "Post"]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:8
  [1m[35m (0.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."post_id" = $1[0m  [["post_id", 37]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:8
  [1m[36mActionText::RichText Load (0.5ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "action_text_rich_texts".* FROM "action_text_rich_texts" WHERE "action_text_rich_texts"."record_id" = $1 AND "action_text_rich_texts"."record_type" = $2 AND "action_text_rich_texts"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4[0m  [["record_id", 37], ["record_type", "Post"], ["name", "content"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:21
  Rendered /home/vyacheslav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actiontext-6.0.1/app/views/action_text/content/_layout.html.erb (Duration: 4.0ms | Allocations: 744)
  [1m[36mActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4[0m  [["record_id", 37], ["record_type", "Post"], ["name", "picture"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:22
  [1m[36mCACHE Author Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "authors".* FROM "authors" WHERE "authors"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:7
  [1m[35m (0.5ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "impressions"."ip_address") FROM "impressions" WHERE "impressions"."impressionable_id" = $1 AND "impressions"."impressionable_type" = $2[0m  [["impressionable_id", 24], ["impressionable_type", "Post"]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:8
  [1m[35m (2.3ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."post_id" = $1[0m  [["post_id", 24]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:8
  [1m[36mActionText::RichText Load (0.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "action_text_rich_texts".* FROM "action_text_rich_texts" WHERE "action_text_rich_texts"."record_id" = $1 AND "action_text_rich_texts"."record_type" = $2 AND "action_text_rich_texts"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4[0m  [["record_id", 24], ["record_type", "Post"], ["name", "content"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:21
  Rendered /home/vyacheslav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actiontext-6.0.1/app/views/action_text/content/_layout.html.erb (Duration: 1.8ms | Allocations: 253)
  [1m[36mActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4[0m  [["record_id", 24], ["record_type", "Post"], ["name", "picture"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:22
  [1m[36mCACHE Author Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "authors".* FROM "authors" WHERE "authors"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:7
  [1m[35m (0.5ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "impressions"."ip_address") FROM "impressions" WHERE "impressions"."impressionable_id" = $1 AND "impressions"."impressionable_type" = $2[0m  [["impressionable_id", 23], ["impressionable_type", "Post"]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:8
  [1m[35m (1.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."post_id" = $1[0m  [["post_id", 23]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:8
  [1m[36mActionText::RichText Load (0.9ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "action_text_rich_texts".* FROM "action_text_rich_texts" WHERE "action_text_rich_texts"."record_id" = $1 AND "action_text_rich_texts"."record_type" = $2 AND "action_text_rich_texts"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4[0m  [["record_id", 23], ["record_type", "Post"], ["name", "content"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:21
  Rendered /home/vyacheslav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actiontext-6.0.1/app/views/action_text/content/_layout.html.erb (Duration: 0.8ms | Allocations: 255)
  [1m[36mActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.6ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4[0m  [["record_id", 23], ["record_type", "Post"], ["name", "picture"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:22
  [1m[36mCACHE Author Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "authors".* FROM "authors" WHERE "authors"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:7
  [1m[35m (0.7ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "impressions"."ip_address") FROM "impressions" WHERE "impressions"."impressionable_id" = $1 AND "impressions"."impressionable_type" = $2[0m  [["impressionable_id", 21], ["impressionable_type", "Post"]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:8
  [1m[35m (0.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."post_id" = $1[0m  [["post_id", 21]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:8
  [1m[36mActionText::RichText Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "action_text_rich_texts".* FROM "action_text_rich_texts" WHERE "action_text_rich_texts"."record_id" = $1 AND "action_text_rich_texts"."record_type" = $2 AND "action_text_rich_texts"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4[0m  [["record_id", 21], ["record_type", "Post"], ["name", "content"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:21
  Rendered /home/vyacheslav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actiontext-6.0.1/app/views/action_text/content/_layout.html.erb (Duration: 1.0ms | Allocations: 253)
  [1m[36mActiveStorage::Attachment Load (1.8ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4[0m  [["record_id", 21], ["record_type", "Post"], ["name", "picture"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:22
  [1m[36mCACHE Author Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "authors".* FROM "authors" WHERE "authors"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:7
  [1m[35m (0.7ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "impressions"."ip_address") FROM "impressions" WHERE "impressions"."impressionable_id" = $1 AND "impressions"."impressionable_type" = $2[0m  [["impressionable_id", 20], ["impressionable_type", "Post"]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:8
  [1m[35m (0.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."post_id" = $1[0m  [["post_id", 20]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:8
  [1m[36mActionText::RichText Load (0.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "action_text_rich_texts".* FROM "action_text_rich_texts" WHERE "action_text_rich_texts"."record_id" = $1 AND "action_text_rich_texts"."record_type" = $2 AND "action_text_rich_texts"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4[0m  [["record_id", 20], ["record_type", "Post"], ["name", "content"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:21
  Rendered /home/vyacheslav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actiontext-6.0.1/app/views/action_text/content/_layout.html.erb (Duration: 0.9ms | Allocations: 253)
  [1m[36mActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4[0m  [["record_id", 20], ["record_type", "Post"], ["name", "picture"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:22
  [1m[36mCACHE Author Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "authors".* FROM "authors" WHERE "authors"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:7
  [1m[35m (0.5ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "impressions"."ip_address") FROM "impressions" WHERE "impressions"."impressionable_id" = $1 AND "impressions"."impressionable_type" = $2[0m  [["impressionable_id", 13], ["impressionable_type", "Post"]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:8
  [1m[35m (0.5ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."post_id" = $1[0m  [["post_id", 13]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:8
  [1m[36mActionText::RichText Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "action_text_rich_texts".* FROM "action_text_rich_texts" WHERE "action_text_rich_texts"."record_id" = $1 AND "action_text_rich_texts"."record_type" = $2 AND "action_text_rich_texts"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4[0m  [["record_id", 13], ["record_type", "Post"], ["name", "content"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:21
  Rendered /home/vyacheslav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actiontext-6.0.1/app/views/action_text/content/_layout.html.erb (Duration: 0.9ms | Allocations: 256)
  [1m[36mActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.5ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4[0m  [["record_id", 13], ["record_type", "Post"], ["name", "picture"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:22
  [1m[36mCACHE Author Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "authors".* FROM "authors" WHERE "authors"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:7
  [1m[35m (0.7ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "impressions"."ip_address") FROM "impressions" WHERE "impressions"."impressionable_id" = $1 AND "impressions"."impressionable_type" = $2[0m  [["impressionable_id", 12], ["impressionable_type", "Post"]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:8
  [1m[35m (0.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."post_id" = $1[0m  [["post_id", 12]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:8
  [1m[36mActionText::RichText Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "action_text_rich_texts".* FROM "action_text_rich_texts" WHERE "action_text_rich_texts"."record_id" = $1 AND "action_text_rich_texts"."record_type" = $2 AND "action_text_rich_texts"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4[0m  [["record_id", 12], ["record_type", "Post"], ["name", "content"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:21
  Rendered /home/vyacheslav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actiontext-6.0.1/app/views/action_text/content/_layout.html.erb (Duration: 0.6ms | Allocations: 253)
  [1m[36mActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4[0m  [["record_id", 12], ["record_type", "Post"], ["name", "picture"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:22
  [1m[36mAuthor Load (0.6ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "authors".* FROM "authors" WHERE "authors"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:7
  [1m[35m (0.7ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "impressions"."ip_address") FROM "impressions" WHERE "impressions"."impressionable_id" = $1 AND "impressions"."impressionable_type" = $2[0m  [["impressionable_id", 3], ["impressionable_type", "Post"]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:8
  [1m[35m (0.5ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."post_id" = $1[0m  [["post_id", 3]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:8
  [1m[36mActionText::RichText Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "action_text_rich_texts".* FROM "action_text_rich_texts" WHERE "action_text_rich_texts"."record_id" = $1 AND "action_text_rich_texts"."record_type" = $2 AND "action_text_rich_texts"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4[0m  [["record_id", 3], ["record_type", "Post"], ["name", "content"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:21
  [1m[36mActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4[0m  [["record_id", 3], ["record_type", "Post"], ["name", "picture"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:22
  [1m[36mCACHE Author Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "authors".* FROM "authors" WHERE "authors"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:7
  [1m[35m (0.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "impressions"."ip_address") FROM "impressions" WHERE "impressions"."impressionable_id" = $1 AND "impressions"."impressionable_type" = $2[0m  [["impressionable_id", 2], ["impressionable_type", "Post"]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:8
  [1m[35m (0.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."post_id" = $1[0m  [["post_id", 2]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:8
  [1m[36mActionText::RichText Load (0.5ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "action_text_rich_texts".* FROM "action_text_rich_texts" WHERE "action_text_rich_texts"."record_id" = $1 AND "action_text_rich_texts"."record_type" = $2 AND "action_text_rich_texts"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4[0m  [["record_id", 2], ["record_type", "Post"], ["name", "content"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:21
  [1m[36mActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4[0m  [["record_id", 2], ["record_type", "Post"], ["name", "picture"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:22
  Rendered collection of posts/_post.html.erb [14 times] (Duration: 340.3ms | Allocations: 73088)
  Rendered posts/index.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 346.1ms | Allocations: 74231)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 417ms (ActiveRecord: 33.2ms | Allocations: 141446)
```

Comment: What does the error actually say? The "Whoops, something went wrong" is the rails default error message, when running in production mode. We (the StackOverflow members) cannot possibly diagnose your problem without *at least* seeing what the error actually says. As a developer, you need to learn how to use the logs.

Comment: Please create a [mre].